# How long on average to brute force a probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Imagine someone is making a 4 digit pin for their computer. 10 possible numbers for each character in the pin (0-9), so the total number of combinations is $10^4$ = 10,000. If someone were to guess through every pin until they got the right one, on average, would it take 5,000 guesses? Logically this makes sense, however, how would a proof be constructed for this? Thanks.

Comment: Consider any arrangement of the set of all passwords. The probability that the correct password is in the first half is exactly $50\%$. So...

Comment: The answer is actually 5,000.5 since there there is a 50% chance the password will be found in the 1-5,000 guesses and 50% it will be found in the 5,001-10,000 guesses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are $n$ possible pins and each are equally likely to occur in the brute force method. Imagine randomly permuting all possible pins from $1, \dots, n$. Then the correct pin can be found with equal probability at any particular site. Let this random variable be denoted by $k$. Then $\mathbb P(k) = 1/n$ for all $k$. Then,
$$ \mathbb E(k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2n} = \frac{n+1}{2}. $$